# In Android how to run the background service?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Can you pls tell what mistake i did in the code for running the BackGround Service.Is Any other code Available for running the BackGround Service.
Is the below Procedure correct.... How to run the background service in android ?

```
FrontEnd.java:
*****************

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FrontEnd extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button btnStartService, btnStopService;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.frontend);

        bindComponents();
        addListener();
        init();
    }

    private void bindComponents() {
        btnStartService = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStartService);
        btnStopService = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStopService);
    }

    private void addListener() {
        btnStartService.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnStopService.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void init() {

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this,BackEndService.class);
        System.out.println("------------------------>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnStartService:
            startService(mIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.btnStopService:
            stopService(mIntent);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

******************************************************************************************************************

BackEndService.java
*********************

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class BackEndService extends Service{

    private static final String tag = "Panacea";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(tag, "onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.d(tag, "onCreate");

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.launcher, getText(R.string.app_name),
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, GmaTestApp01Activity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "BackGround Service", "Project is running", pendingIntent);
        startForeground(1, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Log.d(tag, "onStart startId=" + startId);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(tag, "onStartCommand startId=" + startId);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(tag, "onUnbind");
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(tag, "onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        super.onRebind(intent);
    }
}

*******************************************************************************************************************
frontend.xml
***************
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStartService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/start_service"
         />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStopService"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/stop_service" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]
Update:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Home extends Activity
{



    Integer[] imageIDs = {
            R.drawable.a,
            R.drawable.b,
            R.drawable.c,
            R.drawable.d,
            R.drawable.e,
            R.drawable.f,
            R.drawable.g,
            R.drawable.h,
            R.drawable.i,
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
            View v, int position, long id) 
            {                
                /*Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "pic" + (position + 1) + " selected", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
                int pos= position + 1;

                if(pos == 1)
                {
                     Intent intent = new Intent("com.project.GmaTestApp01Activity");
                     startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if(pos == 2)
                {
                     Intent intent = new Intent("com.project.FrontEnd");
                     startActivity(intent);
                }
                else if(pos == 9)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("com.project.UserProfile");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Coming Soon!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });   

        gridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
    {
        private Context context;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
        {
            context = c;
        }

        //---returns the number of images---
        public int getCount() {
            return imageIDs.length;
        }

        //---returns the ID of an item--- 
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        //---returns an ImageView view---
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = new ImageView(context);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(185, 185));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
            return imageView;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation carefully?

Comment: What do you mean by the mistake you do? Are you not getting what you want?

Comment: Are u getting any error(s) in the above written code?

Comment: @Ree, I will recommend you to read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html document first.

Answer (score 2):

If you BackEndService service not running, it could because you forgot to mention it in the manifest file. If so add the following.

```
    <application 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".YourApp" >

   <activity ....>
    ...
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".BackEndService"></service>
    ....
    </application>
```

Your code seems to be correct.

Comment: i included this <service android:name=".BackEndService"></service> tag in manifest file ..but the above code is running for foreground service only not for background service

Comment: No, it is your  GmaTestApp01Activity Activity which is running on foreground. Your service run in the background and sent notification your GmaTestApp01Activity.

Comment: GmaTestApp01Activity is the Java File for taking readings in Glucometer.

My RequireMent is to run the Glucometer ie GmaTestApp01Activity file in BackGround and while taking the glucometer readings

for the patient , the readings alone has to be displayed in the foreground. pls c the update codings for homepage code

Answer (score 0):

Running background service without notification would not work since Android 8.